# How to match vertical alignment of titlesec with tocloft?

Tags: vertical-alignment, titlesec, tocloft

I want to vertically align the Contents title including the horizontal rules (using `tocloft`) with the Introduction chapter title (using `titlesec`). However, I am confused as both packages seem to measure different spaces. I could match them by trail and error, but can anyone tell me how to measure it exactly? Or should I be trying a different approach?

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\usepackage{sectsty} % Used for sectionrule in ToC
\usepackage{titlesec}   

%---Change Margins
\usepackage[DIV=9,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}

%---Chapter Title Format 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{22pt}{\huge}[\vspace{1.5ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{-22pt}{40pt} % Removes gap above chapters.

%---ToC Format
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont} % ToC title
         %---How to match sectionrule with the 'Introduction' chapter?  
         {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge\sectionrule{0ex}{0pt}{-2ex}{1pt}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont} % chapter titles
         {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont} % section titles
         {\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont} % subsection titles
         {\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont} % chapter page numbers
         {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont} % section page numbers
         {\cftsecfont} 

%---Removes gap above TOC. How to match 'Contents' with chapter 'Introduction'?                     
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-22pt} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction} %Without Chapter Number
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Cats vs Dogs} %With Chapter Number

\lipsum[2]  

\section{History}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Take a seat and feel comfortable ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't doing that easier with `titletoc`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to load `tocloft` with the `titles` option (see section 2.1 in the manual).

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[DIV=9,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false]{typearea}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 

\usepackage{lipsum}     

%---Chapter Title Format 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
  {22pt}
  {\huge}
  [\vspace{1.5ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0mm}{-22pt}{40pt} % Removes gap above chapters.
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{-10pt}} % remove gap before first chapter

%---ToC Format
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont} % chapter titles
         {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont} % section titles
         {\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont} % subsection titles
         {\usefont{T1}{bch}{m}{n}\selectfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont} % chapter page numbers
         {\usefont{T1}{bch}{b}{n}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont} % section page numbers
         {\cftsecfont} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction} %Without Chapter Number
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Cats vs Dogs} %With Chapter Number

\lipsum[2]  

\section{History}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]