# Using tocloft together with titlesec

Tags: titlesec, tocloft

I'm using tocloft for modifying the appearance of my toc. But it will disable the style of the toc title modified with titlesec.

If I disable \usepackage{tocloft} and the two renewcommands, my heading will be underlined.

How can I fix this?

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
% minimal.tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.2pt]}]

  \tableofcontents

  \newpage

  \section{Content}
  Write something
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use option `titles` for `tocloft`: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you load `titlesec` why not use `titletoc`? You can remove the rule under the contents  title by defining a specific format for the unnumbered sections, with the `numberless` key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.2pt]}]
%
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

 \titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}%
 {\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%numbered
 {}%numberless
 {\titlerule*[0.4pc]{.}\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \newpage

  \section{Content}
  Write something

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can load `tocloft` with the `titles` option; also see the manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf.

(from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308414)